# Is there a .exe alternative for Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I was wondering if I could run .exe files on Raspbian. It seems I cannot, but is it possible to run a Raspbian alternative to a .exe file? I tried .jar and .dmg, but neither worked. Is there a type of executable for Raspbian?

Comment: is debian, use .pkg

Comment: No, you cannot execute computer programs on the Raspberry Pi ;)

Answer (score 1):

Any file can be an executable, the extension of the file name has nothing to do with this, but it is determined by the executable permission attribute. These can be script files or compiled binaries, but the latter need to be compiled specifically to run on an ARM processor. Windows `.exe` will not run. (Incidentally `.dmg` Disk Image files are OS X disk images, not executables - they are run by a package program on the Mac.)

Answer (score 0):

Any file can be made executable by adding the executable permission with `sudo chmod +x myfile` but you still need to tell raspbian how to run the file.  Your do this by adding `#!/path/to/program` with path to program being the path to the program you would run the file with.  You are done and you have and executable file ready to use by running `./myfile`

Answer (score 0):

The only way a windows .exe will run on anything linux including the pi is through wine. I am not sure if there is a pi compile of wine as I would never try it. For a .jar these are java scripts. Again not sure if pi has a JRE (java runtime environment) as I would not have a reason to attempt or research this. The .dmg was already answered.

You may want to look into linux basics guides and such on files and programs. Then look at specific platforms/architectures. The pi IS a linux box, but on arm not x86 intel.